# Mongoose Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, next.js

I'm running Mongoose 7.0.1 on Next JS 13.2.2 and React 18.2.0.

I've been looking high and low to find a solution to this issue. I just want to connect to a MongoDB, however, when I import mongoose to the project to connect. This error occurs. Am I doing something wrong?
[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Qbh.png)

[The Code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUqNS.png)

So far I tried to fiddle with the importing process [ie. change from ES6 to Casual JS with "require"] I don't have a clue on what to do seeing as its in the Node Module itsself. I tried different versions of Mongoose as well. But to no avail.

EDIT >>
Here's some screen shots of how I implemented mongoose
[library/mongo/index.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYoXh.png)
[app/api/route.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih4jA.png)

Comment: `ObjectId.prototype.[name of the property you want to define in the prototype chain]`

Comment: Same issue. Anyone has clue?

Answer (score 1):

In `next.config.js` file write the below code:

```
experimental: {
  appDir: true,
  serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["mongoose"],
},
```